# Erro comparando array php

Tags: php

```
$rua[] = {1,1,2,2,2,2};

$countRua = count($rua, COUNT_RECURSIVE);

for ($i=0; $i < $countRua; $i++) { 
    if ($rua[$i] == $rua[$i+1]) {

    }
}
```

Possuo o `for` acima percorrendo um `array` e validando se a posição é igual a próxima posição porém, quando chega na última ele tenta comparar com a posição 7 e retorna o erro abaixo, algum jeito de ajustar isso ?

> Undefined offset: 6

Comment: Se compara com o da frente não pode ir até ao fim

Comment: pq o uso do `COUNT_RECURSIVE`? pode dar um `isset()` em `$rua[$i+1]` que vai dizer se índice existe ou não

Comment: Habito, poderia ter usado só o count mesmo.

Comment: Vai nessa até obter um resultado errado :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode resolver isso verificando se o índice existe com `isset()` a condição do if deve ficar composta dessa forma:

```
if (isset($rua[$i+1]) && $rua[$i] == $rua[$i+1]) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Melhor começar do segundo item e a cada `loop` comparar com o anterior:

```
$rua[] = {1,1,2,2,2,2};

$countRua = count($rua, COUNT_RECURSIVE);

for ($i=1; $i < $countRua; $i++) { 
    if ($rua[$i] == $rua[$i-1]) {

    }
}
```